# Stupid exam task that i can't get to work

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i have this mock exam assignment (not graded or anything) that I cant solve for the life of me. The background: I am making a conversion program from wind in meters per second to watts per hour. I had a chart with ranges of m/s to watts that i made into if scenarios and for some reason i can't get it to work properly. I'm sure it's some stupid error, but please help:)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset:"utf-8">
    <title>Eksamensoppgave</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>m/s --> w/h</h2>
    <input type="number" id="alfa" placeholder="Skriv inn her" autocomplete="off"><button id="knapp">Regn ut</button>
    <div id="felt">
    </div>
    <script>
      var alfa=document.getElementById("alfa");
      var svar=document.getElementById("felt");
      function over() {
        var vind=Math.round(alfa).toFixed(1);
        if (vind >= 0 && vind <= 1.5) {
                svar.innerHTML+="0 watt per time";
            }
            else if (vind >= 1.6 && vind <= 3.3) {
                svar.innerHTML+="2 watt per time";
            }
            else if (vind >= 3.4 && vind <= 5.4) {
                svar.innerHTML+="10 watt per time";
            }
            else if (vind >= 5.5 && vind <= 7.9) {
                svar.innerHTML+="60 watt per time";
            }
            else if (vind >= 8 && vind <= 10.7) {
                svar.innerHTML+="150 watt per time";
            }
            else if (vind >= 10.8 && vind <= 13.8) {
                svar.innerHTML+="400 watt per time";
            }
            else if (vind >= 13.9 && vind <= 17.1) {
                svar.innerHTML+="500 watt per time";
            }
            else if (vind >= 17.2) {
                svar.innerHTML+="0 watt per time";
            }
            else {svar.innerHTML+="Svaret kan ikke oppgis"}
      }
      knapp.onclick=over;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: knapp is never been defined

Comment: You did not define knapp. Use:
```var knapp = document.getElementById('knapp')``` after the two definitions in your script

Comment: Stop _guessing_ what your error could be. Try using the [debugging capabilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript) of your browser. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. Use tools like [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) to find problems with your code immediately. [Rubber Duck Debug](https://rubberduckdebugging.com) your code.

Comment: And learn about [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not working because you are not taking from "alfa" variable the real value of the input.

Just change in your function "over" this line:

`var vind=Math.round(alfa).toFixed(1);`

to this:

`var vind=Math.round(alfa.value).toFixed(1);`

This way it works because you are Math.rounding the value, not the html element related to the input